# Some questions about reconforming to new picture edits

Tags: conform, edl

I have been searching around looking for some basic information on re conforming to new picture edits.  I have come across the write ups on specific auto conform programs which unfortunately do not seem to be compatible with Nuendo, which is the DAW that I use.  The only one that may seem to work is Editrace but still I can not confirm that.

We have not shot the film, but I want to make sure that the post workflow is smooth.  Sound is for the most part a written character in the story, so I have been designing sounds so the editor can use them to cut with and even to use on set in some instances.

This short is a thesis film and normally I require having a picture lock to avoid the issues with new picture cuts, but I know to make the best story and best film possible it will have to bounce back and forth between the picture editor and myself.

I am not really looking for the easy one button auto conform, but more of a breakdown on the process even if I do it manually.  I have never used EDLs and that process, So does anyone have some links or places so I can read up on that process and familiarize myself with what the editor will need to do for me and what I need to do for them.

Unfortunately I am away from my house for the break and all of my books and reference materials are still on my bookshelf at home.  Any information on that process and insight into the professional workflow would be amazing.  The student film workflow is no where near the same process.

Thanks

Michael Gilbert

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you'll get better answers (and answers from the more exerienced members) if you've shown that you've done some research before asking your question. Start off with a google search on how to read an EDL. Once you understand what information you can get from those, you'll probably be able to piece together a general workflow for yourself. Then you'll be able to start off asking more pointed questions that will help you refine your process. Workflow is something you need to continually develop and test; start familiarizing yourself with the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm yet to come across the need to conform myself, but I've had my eye on this program for when the time comes.  It works with Nuendo.

[Virtual Katy](http://virtualkaty.com)

Answer (score 1):

There's some good stuff in John Purcell's book Dialogue Editing for Motion Pictures covering reconforms, edl's etc. Might be worth checking out..

Comment: @Andy Yes, once I get back to my home in New Orleans I'm going to go through all the books I have, and that one is on the shelf, thanks for the heads up, I'll start at that book.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, to make sure we're all being clear, conforming is the process of getting field/production audio onto the timeline in sync with the picture edl. Used to be done with an EDL and a timecode DAT player and an application like Digi's "post conform".

Reconforming is chasing the picture to re-edit a timeline. Done either manually or using Editrace, VK or conformalizer.

Sorry to be anal but it's good to be clear about the differences - there's much disinformation out there!

Comment: @Brent  Yeah at first I did not know the distinction, I'm trying to figure out a process of reconforming, that way all the work I do before final picture lock is not lost and I have to start over.  

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  So after a bit of research, I have realized that the need to conform does not exist in my project,  All the tracks will be just synced up by the assistant editor and I will get them back via omf.

The need for me to be able to reconform would help me out tremendously in preserving the things I will have done during predubs.
Talking with the editor, FCP does not generate a change edl showing the differences between two sequences.  He is able to export edls of both individually.  Am I safe in the conclusion that the change edl is what the programs or services like Editrace generate,  and then actually do a rough conform in your DAW based on those results?